# What are the faceless mermaids like on the inside?

Tags: anatomy, humanoid, merfolk

The faceless mermaids have 2 eyes, on the back of their shoulders. They also have an upwards-facing beak in their chest, which is used to eat. Their head has no eyes or mouth, but does have a nose with functional nostrils

**What is the most plausible way their internal organs link up, specifically in the upper part of the body?**

Comment: Without any criteria for a "best answer", this comes out as opinion-based. Please update the question.

Comment: Sounds kind of like a whale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The head is a nose

An oddly shaped nose, but a nose nonetheless. Their actual head is their torso region, with their brain being somewhere where the heart would be and matches up with the mouth on their chest. Their upper torso does not have a spine or ribcage, being actually a skull, which makes it less flexible but flexibility returns when the spine of the faceless mermaid begins more or less where we'd be used to where the ribs end, with the true neck being what we'd be used to being the abdomen. The hips are where the ribs would start and is where its lungs and heart would be, which allows for better buoyancy control due to their more central positioning to the length of the body. The heart being more central makes more sense as well. Below the hips is the more fish-like lower body we know mermaids for, and is where their digestive system begins, traveling down their fish-like part of their body and is also where kidneys and such are located. Their 'arm' fins have evolved from their ears and are manipulated with the muscles that people can use to move their ears.

The 'neck' of the faceless 'head' is like the trunk of an elephant, without bones but manipulatable, and allows the faceless mermaid to stick their 'head' out of the water to breathe or smell the air without risking their actual heads(their torso region) getting shot at by scared sailors, because I'd shoot anything that looks like slenderman with voldemort's nose too.

Comment: This is so obvious!  +